# How to create pipeline in Azure Devops if one Solution is dependent on other solution

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Am new to Azure Devops. In my Repo i have 2 solutions with multiple projects. Build of one solution is pushed to common folder and other solution refer to that folder for DLL refences. How can this be achieved in Azure devops.

Comment: Extract common dependencies into versioned NuGet packages.

Comment: any examples...?